# Dúvida sobre uma expressão regular específica em Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Utilizando uma expressão regular (regex), gostaria de saber como fazer uma validação que permita tais condições:

> 0-9 / * - + ( ) raiz pi

Mas além de permitir números e os caracteres, gostaria que a expressão permitisse palavras específicas também...

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "Como posso fazer isso?"

Você pode fazer isso utilizando uma expressão regular contendo as condições que você deseja, e testando tal expressão utilizando o javascript para tal feitio, porém você deve especificar tais palavras específicas ou símbolos específicos em seu regex(expressão regular) para que ele possa validar o que é digitado.

A expressão que você deseja inicialmente pode ser interpretada desta forma:

```
var regex = /^[√\.0-9\/*\-+\()\√\π]*$/g;
```

*Obs:* como você não especificou se *pi* e *raiz* eram para ser representados em símbolo ou de forma literal, utilizei os seus respectivos símbolos.

## Exemplo funcional:

```js
textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
textInput.addEventListener("keydown", regularexp);

buttonPi = document.getElementById('pi');
buttonPi.addEventListener("click", inserePi);

buttonRaiz = document.getElementById('raiz');
buttonRaiz.addEventListener("click", insereRaiz);

// 0-9 / * - + ( ) raiz pi [^0-9/*-+()√¯π]

function regularexp(e){
    console.log(e);
    var txt     = e.key;
    console.log(txt);
    var aryReservedKeys = [  
                             8//backspace
                           ,16//Shift
                           ,17//Ctrl
                           ,35//End
                           ,36//Home
                           ,37//ArrowLeft
                           ,38//ArrowUp
                           ,39//ArrowRight
                           ,40//ArrowDown
                           ,46//delete
                           ];
    var regex = /^[√\.0-9\/*\-+\()\√\π]*$/g;
    var isReservedCharacter = (aryReservedKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1);
    if( !regex.test(txt) && !(isReservedCharacter) ) {
        console.log("Not Match");
        var winEvent = e || window.event;
        winEvent.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }else{
        console.log("Match");
    }
}

function inserePi(){   textInput.value += 'π'; }
function insereRaiz(){ textInput.value += '√'; }
```

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input id=textInput type=text value="((√31+50)-(45*55)+(5*5)/(√50*π))" />
<input id=pi type=button value="Inserir Pi" />
<input id=raiz type=button value="Inserir Raiz" />
```

## Explicação

Note que eu utilizei um regex e adicionei um evento *keydown* que escuta ações no elemento `<input id=textInput>` do qual verifica qual caractere foi digitado pelo usuário e o descarta caso o mesmo não seja validado pela expressão regular, ou seja ele cancela a ação.

Também, eu adicionei algumas ações reservadas que eventualmente podem ser utilizadas pelo usuário como exceções, para que não haja perda de usabilidade em seu campo de texto, como podes ver tais teclas comentadas com seus respectivos códigos no array *aryReservedKeys*.

Como os códigos individuais de cada símbolo geralmente não são conhecidos, criei dois botões que inserem automaticamente no fim do texto do campo de texto o *pi* e a *raiz*.

## Adicionando mais símbolos/palavras

Bom para adicionar um símbolo é extremamente simples, você apenas deve adicionar logo após o ultimo símbolo validado pelo regex uma barra invertida e em seguida o símbolo desejado como por exemplo:
`\%`
Assim o novo regex ficaria disposto desta forma:

```
var regex = /^[√\.0-9\/*\-+\()\√\π\%]*$/g;
```

Agora para palavras, basta escreve-las exatamente como são entre parênteses em seguida, ficando desta forma, por exemplo, vamos adicionar a palavra *palavraTeste*:

```
var regex = /^[√\.0-9\/*\-+\()\√\π*]*(palavraTeste)*$/g;
```

### Extra

Para descobrir quais expressões regulares estão corretas de acordo com o que você quer fazer, e para entender o funcionamento da expressão regular, utilize [este site](https://regex101.com) como referência, ele é muito bom.

Answer (score 1):

Para permitir isso `0-9 / * - + ( ) raiz pi` seria algo assim `[0-9/\*\+\-\(\)\.]`.

Para palavras especificas seria algo mais ou menos assim: `(palavraUm|palavraDois|palavraTres)`

Sugiro que leia este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) para entender melhor como que funciona.

Neste outro [link](http://www.piazinho.com.br/#video) tem videos tutoriais em português.